Defining subsequence to prove that Cauchy in measure implies convergence in measure
I'm on my way to prove Egoroff's theorem but something is bugging me regarding a previous theorem.
The statement on Folland's Real Analysis is:

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. Then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e. Moreover, if also $f_n\rightarrow g$ in measure, then $g=f$ a.e.

The proof starts with the claim:

We can choose a subsequence $\{g_j\}=\{f_{n_j}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that if $$E_j=\{x\in X; \ |g_j(x)-g_{j+1}(x)| \geq 2^{-j}\},$$ then $\mu(E_j)\leq 2^{-j}$.

I'm trying to prove that such a subsequence exists. My attempt uses the Cauchy in measure hypothesis to conclude that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(\{x\in X; \ |f_n(x)-f_{n+1}(x)|\geq 2^{-j}\})=0,\quad \forall j\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Thus, for all $j$, there is natural number $N(j)$ for which the measure of the set with the desired property will be bounded by $2^{-j}$. I chose $n_1$ as the smallest natural number greater than $N(1)$ and defined $g_1=f_{n_1}$, $g_2=f_{n_1+1}$. I can do the same for all odd numbers and it'll be true that $\mu(E_j)\leq 2^{-j}$ for all $j$ that are odd.
Though, with this construction, there's no guarantee that $g_2$ and $g_3$ will behave properly, for instance. Is there a better way to define this subsequence?
